# How to know in Outlook VBA whether the current view is a search results view?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to perform a VBA action on each Outlook.Explorer_SelectionChange event, however, only if the Explorer is showing search results. Is there any way to determine whether you are currently displaying search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to parse `.FolderPath`.

```vb
Sub identifySearchFolder()

    Dim currFolder As folder
    Dim currFolderPath As String
    
    Dim txtSearch As String
    Dim pathSearch As String
    
    txtSearch = "received:this week"
    pathSearch = "\search folders\"
    
    Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set currFolder = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder: " & currFolder
    
    If InStr(currFolderPath, pathSearch) Then
        Debug.Print pathSearch & " found in non-search FolderPath: " & ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.FolderPath
    Else
        Debug.Print "ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.FolderPath: " & ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.FolderPath
    End If
    
    With ActiveExplorer
        .ClearSearch ' Clear previous search if any
        .Search txtSearch, olSearchScopeAllFolders
    End With
    
    Set currFolder = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Debug.Print "ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder: " & currFolder
    
    currFolderPath = currFolder.FolderPath
    Debug.Print currFolder.FolderPath
    
    If InStr(currFolderPath, pathSearch) Then
        Debug.Print pathSearch & " found in FolderPath: " & ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.FolderPath
    Else
        Debug.Print ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.FolderPath
    End If
    
End Sub
```